# React Native - yarn ios doesn't work after initializing the project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm a new user to Mac OS and its system and M1.
After install dependencies of my project and trying yarn iOS

```
* BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cemfgnbnzwyxlydpmalbfirprbcu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNScreens.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNSScreenViewEvent.o /Users/Trampo/node_modules/react-native-screens/ios/RNSScreenViewEvent.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNScreens' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

Comment: And look on your package.json file. Maybe there's a different starting command.

Comment: Are you using Rosetta Terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change React Native version to 0.64.4,
run yarn,
cd iOS
pod install
pod update,
Xcode and terminal (iterm2) to running with rosetta.

Works, thanks.

Comment: To help other people with this same problem, please mark this as the official Answer.

Answer (score 0):

For React Native you also have to maintain the ios pod files. So, go to your ios folder and update your pods.

Terminal command:

```
cd ios/ && pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: After using this command, the problem persist